# Destacar palavra na busca com php

Tags: php

Estou tentando destacar uma determinada palavra na busca da seguinte forma:

O usuário digita na busca a palavra **destacar** e essa palavra ficaria ressaltada no texto. Para isso, tentei com os 02 códigos abaixo, mas não consegui:

**Primeiro código:**

```
$buscar = "destacar";
$texto = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur destacar adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";

$tarjado = preg_replace("/($buscar)/i", "<span style='background-color:#FF0;color:#F00'>\\1</span>", $texto);
echo $texto;
```

**Segundo código:**

```
$buscar = "destacar";
$texto = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur destacar adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";

$tarjado = preg_replace( sprintf( '/\b(%s)\b/i', is_array( $buscar ) ? implode( '|', $buscar ) : $buscar ), '<span class="font-weight: bold">$1</span>', $texto );
echo $texto;
```

Comment: Note que está usando `echo $texto`, ao invés do `echo $tarjado`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `str_replace`, normalmente:

```
<?php

$buscar = "destacar";
$texto = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur destacar adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";

$texto = str_replace($buscar, '<mark>'.$buscar.'</mark>', $texto);
echo $texto;
```

Comment: Que descuido meu. Tem razão  Inkeliz, estava dando um echo na variável errada.

Comment: Obrigado Inkeliz.

Comment: Sugestão: utilizar a tag `<mark>`, pois aumenta a semântica da página.

Answer (score 0):

Só para reforçar aqui no post, caso tenham um texto muito grande e queira apenas destacar um trecho desse texto com a palavra buscada ressaltada, podem fazer dessa forma:

```
$buscar = "destacar";
$texto = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur destacar adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";

$trecho = preg_match_all ("/([\P{Cc}]{0,45}){$buscar}([\P{Cc}]{0,45})/i", $texto, $testar);

foreach($testar[0] as $teste){
        $tarjado = preg_replace("/($buscar)/i", "<span style='font-weight: bold'>\\1</span>", $teste);
        echo  "...".$tarjado."...";
}
```

**Saída:**

...consectetur **destacar** adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...